# DO refuses table import due "no primary key" yet I have a primary key

Tags: mysql, database, import, migration, digital-ocean

DigitalOcean refuses to import my tables after the last patch (php8). It gives me the following error

> ERROR 3750 (HY000) at line 30: Unable to create or change a table
> without a primary key, when the system variable
> 'sql_require_primary_key' is set. Add a primary key to the table or
> unset this variable to avoid this message. Note that tables without a
> primary key can cause performance problems in row-based replication,
> so please consult your DBA before changing this setting.

The table does have a primary key, but I wonder if the import file needs to be structured differently? the error seems to stop at line 30 which is
**CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoleClaims` (**
and the primary key is not defined until further down, in the **ALTER TABLE** clause.

I have googled the error and some suggest to contact DO and have them remove the PrimaryKey restriction on the DB but I don't want (and shouldn't need) that, since my table has a primary key.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Värd: s369.loopia.se
-- Tid vid skapande: 29 jan 2023 kl 22:12
-- Serverversion: 10.3.36-MariaDB-log
-- PHP-version: 8.1.13

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Databas: `na_se`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellstruktur `AspNetRoleClaims`
--

CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoleClaims` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RoleId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ClaimType` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClaimValue` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Index för dumpade tabeller
--

--
-- Index för tabell `AspNetRoleClaims`
--
ALTER TABLE `AspNetRoleClaims`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  ADD KEY `IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId` (`RoleId`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT för dumpade tabeller
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT för tabell `AspNetRoleClaims`
--
ALTER TABLE `AspNetRoleClaims`
  MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- Restriktioner för dumpade tabeller
--

--
-- Restriktioner för tabell `AspNetRoleClaims`
--
ALTER TABLE `AspNetRoleClaims`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `AspNetRoles` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: add the primary key and the auto_increment to the create table, your sql mode doesn't allow creating a table without the primary key and altering is no substitude

Comment: Als AspNetRoles has to exist prior to to the create table you are making

Comment: This file (and a large amount of others) are generated by export from various DB tools (phpmyadmin is only one of the many I tried). There must be a setting I can make while exporting that creates a file that conforms to these requirements, yes? Do you know what the setting would be?

Comment: Maybe https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary with --create-options https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_create-options

Comment: I have never used a CLI for DB migrations, only GUIs. I also don't have CLI access to some of the source DBs I'm moving. If that options is common, shouldn't it be togglable on at least some (or even one?) of the GUi tools for DB management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others pointed out, the primary key must be defined already in the CREATE TABLE statement. None of the GUI database managers I have coma across offer that option.

The workaround that worked for me was to export the data from the remote provider, import it to my local MySQL DB, and from there run the CLI tool mysqldump on it (which creates the output required for import to DigitalOcean).

In case someone else is as clueless or baffled as I was =)